# Cant connect to sql server database using ip

Tags: sql-server, database, sql, sql-server-2012

I've created a sql server database on server `A`. I was always using Windows Authentication to connect, but now I want to connect to database from server `B`. Then, I added a new user to database and turned `Sql Authentication ON`.

Now, I can connect to database from server `A` using:

```
1 ) Windows Authentication
-Server name: PC\SQLEXPRESS

or

2) SQL Authentication
-Server name: localhost\SQLEXPRESS,1433
-Login: new_user
-Password: example
```

But I cant connect with my public ip which is for example: `133.155.84.28`. I have to use localhost. That means I can connect with database from server "B".

I went to `SQL Server Configuration Manager/Protocols for SQLEXPRESS/TCP IP/IP Adresses`. Here you can see which ip adressess let me login to my local SQLEXPRESS:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BiOs.png)

I can't connect using neither `133.155.84.28` nor `127.0.0.1`. Only `localhost`. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in the SQL Server Configuration Manager utility, none of your actual IP addresses have been activated.

## IP Configuration

You have to set the following option for the IP addresses you want to connect to:

```
Enabled           : Yes
```

## Port Configuration

If you want to connect to the default 1433 port, then you would also have to set the following:

```
TCP Dynamic Ports : 
TCP Port          : 1433
```

Leave the Dynamic Port blank/empty and then Apply/Close the Configuration Manager. You will have to restart the SQL Server for these changes to be applied.

**Edit:**
I just realised that you probably have the following option set on the initial screen of the SQL Server Configuration Manager utility for the TCP/IP properties in the **Protocol** register:

```
Listen All        : Yes
```

Which basically means my answer might not be helpful unless you specifically set `Listen All : No` and then activate the IP address in the **IP Addresses** register.

If you don't see your public IP Address in the SQL Server Configuration Manager in the IP Properties, then SQL Server is unaware of your public IP.